# Split Search/Replace preview vertically (top/bottom)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, search/replace preview is shown with 'before' view on left and 'after' on right.
For longer code lines or smaller screens this is quite impractical:

[image]

Is there a possiblity to open the split view vertically?

(I have tried setting `workbench.editor.splitInGroupLayout` to `vertical`)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I found was to enable inline view (in preview editor's top right overflow menu):

[image]